# How to display recently installed programs and when they were installed?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

I have a Windows XP and I just installed about 12 new programs. Big mistake!  Before I installed these programs, my internet connection was running great.  But now after installing and restarting my laptop, the internet is crawling.  How can I see what was changed?

Hint: prior to installing these 12 programs, I installed IE version 8.  So probably if I removed that it would fix it, but the problem is I need IE in order for my SQL/C# web application to work properly.

Comment: Could be that some programs (especially Microsoft ones) are automatically downloading software updates.  If you wait awhile, the problem could resolve itself.

Comment: While I agree that Robert's answer is the most likely, what is the list of apps you installed?  We might be able to point to other potential culprits as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) groups recently installed programs by default. I'm not sure if the free version has that feature, but you can get a full trial for the Pro version.

If you don't want to install another utility, Add/Remove Programs can sort by last used date. It's not quite the same, but it might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: I second.  Highly, highly recommend Revo...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try System Restore? Most probably it would have made restore points before installing the applications.

And i advise that you post your question in https://superuser.com/
This is a programming forum and you might not get the answers you need :)